# altair selection in multiple charts

Tags: python, vega, vega-lite, altair

I have a data frame with columns: 'sex', 'urb', 'age', 'time', 'value'.

I need to select one element from 'sex' and 'urb' and multiple from 'age' column, then make an interactive line chart with 'time' on x axis, 'value' on y and age in the legend.

I add selection_multi() to separate mark_rect(e.g. y='sex:O', no x axis) for each 'sex', 'urb' and 'age' columns.

I expect the mark_line() to daw lines based on selection_multi(). E.g., if I select:

1. 'Male' from 'sex'
2. 'Urban' from 'urb'
3. '20s' and '40s' from 'age

then 2 lines:

1. Male - Urban - 20s
2. Male - Urban - 40s

are drawn.

However, selection does not work as I expect. E.g. if I select 'Male' from 'sex' mark_rect() and 'Urban' from 'urb' mark_rect(), then 'Female' is automatically selected in 'sex' mark_rect(). It is impossible to select 'Male' AND 'Urban', even though there are lines with 'Male' and 'Urban' in the data frame.

What am I doing wrong?

[Dashboard should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHd9k.png)

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

levels = it.product(['Male', 'Female'], ['Urban', 'Rural'], ['20s', '30s', '40s'], ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'])
data = pd.DataFrame(list(levels), columns=['sex', 'urb', 'age', 'time'])
data['value'] = [x for x in range(1, 13) for y in range(6)]

selector = alt.selection_multi(fields=['sex', 'urb', 'age'])

ax = alt.Axis(offset=-60, orient='right', domain=False, ticks=False, title=None)
clr = alt.condition(selector, alt.value('lightblue'), alt.value('lightgray'), legend=None)

sex = alt.Chart(data, title='sex (single selection)').mark_rect().encode(y=alt.Y('sex:N', axis=ax), color=clr).properties(width=60, height=40).add_selection(selector)
urb = alt.Chart(data, title='urb (single selection)').mark_rect().encode(y=alt.Y('urb:N', axis=ax), color=clr).properties(width=60, height=40).add_selection(selector)
age = alt.Chart(data, title='age (multi selection) ').mark_rect().encode(y=alt.Y('age:N', axis=ax), color=clr).properties(width=60, height=60).add_selection(selector)

line = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(x='time:O', y='value:Q', color='age:O').transform_filter(selector).properties(width=200, height=200)


sex_urb = alt.Chart(data).mark_rect().encode(x='sex:O', y='urb:O').transform_filter(selector).properties(width=40, height=40)
sex_age = alt.Chart(data).mark_rect().encode(x='sex:O', y='age:O').transform_filter(selector).properties(width=40, height=40)
urb_age = alt.Chart(data).mark_rect().encode(x='urb:O', y='age:O').transform_filter(selector).properties(width=40, height=40)
sex_urb_base = alt.Chart(data).mark_rect().encode(x='sex:O', y='urb:O', color=alt.value('white')).properties(width=40, height=40)
sex_age_base = alt.Chart(data).mark_rect().encode(x='sex:O', y='age:O', color=alt.value('white')).properties(width=40, height=40)
urb_age_base = alt.Chart(data).mark_rect().encode(x='urb:O', y='age:O', color=alt.value('white')).properties(width=40, height=40)

alt.hconcat(alt.vconcat(sex, urb, age), alt.vconcat(sex_urb_base + sex_urb, sex_age_base + sex_age, urb_age_base + urb_age), line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have a single selector that triggers on `'sex'`, `'urb'`, and `'age'`. From your description, it seems like you want multiple selectors that trigger independently.

Try creating three selectors, for example

```
selector_sex = alt.selection_single(fields=['sex'])
selector_urb = alt.selection_single(fields=['urb'])
selector_age = alt.selection_multi(fields=['age'])
```

and use them in the various places within your dashboard.